# Multiple divs, with synchronised scrolling and same height

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I want to implement something similar with the GitHub conflict solver system, I have multiple versions, represented by values, displayed in columns, I want to be able to select different values from different columns in order to compose my new solution.
I have to make sure that all of the columns scroll at the same time, and the height for each row representing a parameter of the version have the same height, I will leave an example below.
[Image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2CAM.png)

I implemented a working solution using simple html tables, and it provides most of the functionality , excepting the ability to group rows, collapse them and expand. I was wondering if you have a better solution/suggestion for implementing this or should. continue with tables + adding some query to implement the grouping functionality?

I have to mention that I m using Angular for this project.

Comment: It's only css. You can use some like use [bootstrap cards layout](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/card/#card-layout) or using [cssGrid](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)

Answer (score 0):

You could investigate the option of using [AG Grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/) for the features that you have to implement:

- [scroll sync tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2vduRLXiRdQ)
- [row grouping](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/grouping-group-rows/)

Comment: Already investigated AG grid, and it is a no go for various specific reasons, but thank you for the suggestion

Comment: Out of curiosity, which would be those reasons ?